# Why am I not getting reopen votes?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I saw my scherzo question go from open to on hold. I edited it and voted for it to reopen but 5 votes are needed for the question to be reopened.

I saw the reason why it was put on hold as being unclear what I was asking so I added more information in my edit, hoping to get some reopen votes. But why am I not getting any, even after the additional information was added?

Here is the link to my scherzo question:

[How do I put the joke into the music?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/80534/how-do-i-put-the-joke-into-the-music)

Comment: One thing that I still find unclear is: what do you mean by "the joke"? What joke? Do you mean **a** joke? (as in any joke) "**The** joke" means one particular joke, and it's not clear which particular joke you mean.

Comment: I suppose I do mean a joke because there is more than one type of musical joke that has been used in scherzos.

Answer (score 4):

It is still not clear what you are asking.

What answer do you expect? Do you want someone to come up with a humorous aspect that could be added to your scherzo? If so, that would be extremely broad, as there could be numerous ways to do it.

Is it something more like General Nuisance's comment? If so, I'm not sure that is really an answer either - as it is really just reiterating your question in a different way.